# Matching exactly 2 characters in string - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i query a column with `Names` of people to get only the names those contain **exactly 2** `“a”` ?

I am familiar with `%` symbol that's used with `LIKE` but that finds all names even with 1 `a` , when i write `%a` , but i need to find only those have **exactly** 2 characters.

Please explain - Thanks in advance

> Table Name: "People"
>
> Column Names: "Names, Age, Gender"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `'_a'`. `'_'` is a single character wildcard where `'%'` matches 0 or more characters.

If you need more advanced matches, use regular expressions, using `REGEXP_LIKE`. See [Using Regular Expressions With Oracle Database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm).

And of course you can use other tricks as well. For instance, you can compare the length of the string with the length of the same string but with 'a's removed from it. If the difference is 2 then the string contained two 'a's. But as you can see things get ugly real soon, since length returns 'null' when a string is empty, so you have to make an exception for that, if you want to check for names that are exactly 'aa'.

```
select * from People
where
  length(Names) - 2 = nvl(length(replace(Names, 'a', '')), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked :) I didn't know about usage of `nvl` since i am new to sql. I would like if you +1 the question as well sine it may help many others struck in same situation - Thankyou

Comment: Done. :) Note that `nvl` is an Oracle invention and is not common to SQL. Other databases like SQL server use `isnull`. A more portable alternative is `coalesce`, but it has more letters and is harder to spell. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you're asking for two `a` characters search for a string with two a's but not with three.

```
select *
  from people
 where names like '%a%a%'
   and name not like '%a%a%a%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to replace everything that is not an `a` with nothing and check if the resulting String is exactly two characters long:

```
select names 
from people
where length(regexp_replace(names, '[^a]', '')) = 2;
```

This can also be extended to deal with uppercase `A`s:

```
select names 
from people
where length(regexp_replace(names, '[^aA]', '')) = 2;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/09bc6

Answer (score -1):

`select * from People where names like '__';` also ll work

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow mate, The question you're answering already have many answers and one of them is accepted too. So if you can't add more content to your answer please don't repeat answers. First check whether you're having something new and working or you're repeating others answer before posting your answer.